# SpriteKit best way to transition to and from a scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to implement a menu scene which then launches a game in a new scene. Below is my solution, but I was wondering if this is the preferred way to achieve the desired effect or if anyone else had any alternatives.

GameScene.swift

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let gameScene = MainGameScene(fileNamed: "MainGameScene")
        gameScene?.initMenuScene(self)
        let transition = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.0)

        self.view?.presentScene(gameScene!, transition: transition)
    }
```

MainGameScene.swift

```
class MainGameScene: SKScene
{

var menuScene: SKScene?

func initMenuScene(scene: SKScene)
{
    self.menuScene = scene
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    let transition = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.0)

    self.view?.presentScene(menuScene!, transition: transition)

}
```

}

Comment: I think it is ok. You are presenting your MainGameScene by touches and getting back to your GameScene from MainGameScene by presenting scene.

Comment: One thing I would avoid doing is creating your  scenes on the touch event,  I would create the scenes in a loading phase, this way when you present, there is no pause in the transition

Comment: Thanks for that, useful feedback